# How to show that a linear additive code is contained in its dual (where all dual codewords are orthogonal to themselves and others)

Tags: group-theory, finite-fields, orthogonality, coding-theory, dual-spaces

Say $C$ is a linear additive code over $GF(4)$.

Let the dual code $C^{\perp}=${$u \in GF(4)|u \cdot \bar{c}=0, \forall c \in C$}.

Say if I know that every element of $C^{\perp}$ is orthogonal to itself and to other elements of $C^{\perp}$. For example $$u_{i}\cdot \bar{u_{j}}=0, \forall u_{i},u_{j} \in C^{\perp}.$$

Then how would I prove that $C$ is contained in $C^{\perp}$? I think it should be possible, but perhaps I am not making the criteria strict enough?

---

I wonder if it is something to do with the fact that $c \in C$ must be orthogonal (wrt Hermitian inner product) to every $c^{\perp} \in C^{\perp}$? And every  $c^{\perp} \in C^{\perp}$ is self-orthogonal...but I can't really get it straight in my head.

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you're assuming. Is there a specific place you're drawing this question from, so we could look at a reference? :)

Comment: Hi, I think I was confused myself. I think I was incorrectly assuming from Calderbank et.al's paper "Quantum Error Correction via codes over $GF(4)$, that every linear additive code is self-orthogonal however, I do not necessarily think this is the case. Instead, it is more correct to say that "a linear additive code $C$ is self-orthogonal with respect to  the Trace Inner Product if and only if it is self-orthogonal with respect to the Hermitian inner product". I willl close this question shortly as it incorrectly (I think) assumes that all linear additive codes are self-dual.